# Moderator posted a strange-looking question and deleted it right away; is something wrong?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Just now I was watching `ios` questions page and suddenly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888330/tes-test-test-tes-tes-te-stestset-setset-setsets) question appears.

It's clear that someone hacked Jeremy Banks ♦'s account. It also shows that Jeremy Banks deleted that same question after an interval of one minute.

Is Jeremy's account hacked? Or was he testing whether he can post the question?

Comment: His calling the question "tes test test tes tes te stestset setset setsets" and using a copy&paste of a Stack Overflow page as content speaks for the latter.

Comment: Nah, he's done test questions before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350524/drafts-get-your-very-own-for-a-limited-time-only-some-conditions-apply

Comment: He should take that to the sandbox. I would suspend him!....oh wait...

Comment: He's new to the job, probably playing around with his new toys... ;)

Comment: This comes off as tattling more than a sincere question.

Comment: @TankorSmash If a moderator's account were in fact compromised, that'd definitely be of concern to the community. It comes of as curiosity and concern, nothing worse.

Comment: @deceze, He should use a less used tag to play around in then, or even create his own.

Comment: I think he can tell us if somebody mentions him, like this: @JeremyBanks

Comment: Can we burninate this [meta-tag:hack]  tag right now? Or at least change it to hacked-account?

Comment: I wonder what would've happened if you had flagged it before it got deleted.

Comment: @TylerH given the sensational initial title, I doubt that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The initial title comes of as concerned, if anything. That only serves to further my point.

Comment: @TylerH But the title reads "Hack on moderator account". Without even a question mark.

Comment: how can you have so much free time as a developer?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Right, many questions don't use proper grammar ever, let alone on their first revision. Further, if it is a statement, that just indicates *more* concern.

Comment: I blame the parents.

Comment: I don't see any edits on the post to change the title, but that could be just me.

Comment: @MrLister - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/291552/1

Comment: @UriAgassi Oh, _this_ question, I thought they meant the test one.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### *This message is a test, please ignore...*

Nothing to worry about! I've been examining the moderator tools -- in particular, the log of recently-deleted questions. I created and deleted that post as part of an experiment about when questions would show up. I was hoping to delete it before anybody saw, but that's tough when so many of you are watching.

If there's a next time, I'll pick a low-traffic tag instead.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery?

Comment: you can use [recordmydesktop]

Comment: Clearly the moderator tools for discovering low-traffic tags are severely underpowered.

Comment: I can answer it!

Comment: Wouldnt it be rather simple to implement a dev / quality environment that is simply a daily copy of the meta / stackoverflow site / db?  I would think this is a lousy way of testing as you insert test data into a production database...

Comment: @jonh Such a test environment exists, but only the staff have access. It is not open to moderators.

Comment: Right but I almost think one should be done for maybe just the moderators, I mean creating questions then simply deleting them (I know they are deleted but still) is just not ideal in a production environment.

Comment: I think you should create a new tag  for moderators to use for test questions, something like [moderator-test], but only a suggestion, please ignore this if it is against the rules.

Comment: This is exactly what the hackers would say... How do we know this is the REAL Jeremy Banks?

Comment: @Laurel How? Hmm... (a) Because I'm no longer a moderator, so there's not much reason for a hacker to steal my account, and (b) if they hack it away, [I'll hack it right back!](http://stackoverflow.com/about/security) ;)

Answer (score 55):

That's Jeremy Banks for you.

Feel free to ignore. We don't really have any other way to test things like the quality filter, so don't be alarmed when you find us posting apparent test questions or showing up as conspicuously-named sock puppets.

Comment: ClockBolt, or Gortok, or Nog-Shine, or... well.. can't let the community in on too many of our secrets.

Comment: Serge Geocker​​

Comment: So I get that the term sock puppet means a second account for the intention of gaining some kind of advantage. I am just not at all sure why it's called a sock puppet. My best guess is an uncleverer disguise, but I am still not sure. Am I on the money or is there a point I am missing?

Comment: @robbmj It's called a sock puppet because the account isn't a real person.. it's a person pretending to be someone else, just like a [sock puppet](http://bartersauce.com/sites/default/files/images/trades/SockTrade.jpg)

Comment: @robbmj: [Of course, that question has already been asked on Stack Exchange.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123733/what-does-sock-puppeting-mean)