# Is there some backstory to this highly upvoted, wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, wrong-answers

I'm puzzled by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145784/469708) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491649/469708).

1. The answer has 19 upvotes (and 1 downvote).
2. The answer is completely wrong:

   - The solution rotates the text (which was not asked for).
   - The solution does not vertically center the text (which was asked for).
   - The answer <strike>claims</strike> implies that you need to use a Label instead of TextBlock (which is not true; a LayoutTransform can be applied to a TextBlock, too).
3. There is a comment that seems to reference the content of the answer, but mentions something that is not actually in the answer. (This is just my impression and may be wrong)
4. The answer was never edited.
5. The question was edited, but not substantially. The intent was always the same.

Is there some hidden history such as edits or a bad question merge, or how did this answer garner so many upvotes?

Comment: 2c. Actually the answer says you *can* use, not that you *need* to use a Label.

Comment: There's no merge in the revision history

Comment: @TylerH True, but in the context of the question (where TextBlock does not provide the property in question) it sounds like switching to Label is a necessary part of the solution, which it is not.

Comment: For your point 3, I think the commenter read the answer about as carefully as the answerer read the question. People don't read.

Comment: Upvoted. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: How is 19 upvotes "so many" when the top voted answer has nearly 150 votes *and* there are two more answers rated above it?

Comment: Also, rotating text 270 degrees does make it vertical. It might not be the right "kind" of vertical, but for people who neither read the answer nor the question carefully this might be good enough.

Comment: Ah, the meta effect. The question had 19 up and 1 down. Now it has 24 up and 4 down.

Comment: It was upvoted because it worked for someone. It was accepted because it worked for the person answering the question. Lots of questions have really good answers that are tangential to the question or an all our replacement for the question. That's a good thing!

Comment: Part of the problem: downvotes cost rep, so it is strategically bad to downvote.

Answer (score 61):

Those kind of votes are brought in by Google.  Which puts this Q+A at the top of list when programmers query for "wpf vertical text".  Such visitors may well have a use for that Label solution.  And are thus apt to vote it up.

Comment: That sounds plausible, indeed.

Comment: Should I or someone else edit the answer to add a note that it answers a different question?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus No, absolutely not.  You can add a comment if you want though.

Comment: Also feel free to downvote it if you haven't already, @SebastianNegraszus.

Comment: I'm puzzled by this answer to this question... 1) The answer doesn't address whether there is some backstory to upvoted, wrong answer; and 2) The answer does not address whether there some hidden history such as edits or a bad question merge.

Comment: The rumors that there is a "backstory" are greatly exaggerated.  Not everything is a deep dark secret.

Comment: @HansPassant that is exactly what they WANT us to think! ;)

Comment: @AndrewOdri - [Question timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1491649/timeline) shows the upvotes arrived in a trickle over time

Comment: @AndrewOdri: Self-demonstrating posts are the best part of meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Hahah thanks; I used to try to make overtly valuable contributions to meta, but I've found that passive-aggressive trolling is received much more kindly :P

Comment: @AndrewOdri: I've had [considerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303253/asking-the-same-question-again-but-with-different-words/303254#303254) [acceptance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage/295674#295674) [either way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291552/moderator-posted-a-strange-looking-question-and-deleted-it-right-away-is-someth/291650#comment183353_291650), so do whatever seems most beneficial.