# How is this a good answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I today came along this "answer":

[How to convert a string to lower or upper case in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020568/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-or-upper-case-in-ruby/1021299#1021299)

This "answer" doesn’t address the question at all. This answer basically says "look, here’s how you can get a list of names of all String methods, figure out yourself which one is the right".

If this is considered a good answer (100 upvotes!) it could basically be posted under any question asking about a Ruby string method, couldn’t it? (Would fit in well in [Reverse a string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057967/reverse-a-string-in-ruby) for instance)

**Can somebody please explain to me why this is considered a good answer?**

Comment: It is an answer to _"how to print all methods available on a class"_ and therefore not "not an answer".

Comment: Ah, context. My old nemesis. We meet again.

Comment: @Daedalus My question is definitely not why my flag was declined, but why this is considered a good answer.

Comment: @idmean The duplicate I vtc'd this question as explains that under the last point: `Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer.`  If it looks like an answer; it's an answer.  If its a bad answer, you can downvote it, but flag reviewers do not have access to the question as context.

Comment: @Daedalus "why this is considered a *good* [100 upvotes] answer"

Comment: @idmean Forgive me; its 2am and therefore late; I'll retract my vote.

Comment: @Daedalus I realize my flag was wrong but that was not my question. I changed the first paragraph to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @idmean Thanks for that; that's what likely threw me off.

Comment: It is a lovely answer to an eye-watering trite question.  The kind of question that I never thought belong here, but we have to put up anyway, thank heavens that's all done with.  It is a "here's the fish" answer.

Comment: I think what Hans means is that this is a "teach a man to fish" answer, rather than a "here's a fish" answer. You are free to disagree that this a helpful answer. Express your opinion by clicking the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 3):

This is how: There are already answers that mention canonical `String#upcase` and `String#downcase` methods. But in addition to these, there is eg. method `String#capitalize` and even frequently used methods from 3rd party libraries, such as `ActiveSupport`'s `#camelize`, which is marginally related to the topic at hand. Asking about `#upcase` and `#downcase` in Ruby is obviously a newbie question and the author of the answer you didn't like wanted to point the newbies to the right thing for them to do -- reading the `String` class documentation from A to Z. However, this still won't cover the third party methods which are frequently available eg. in Rails projects. You can learn about those by listing the available methods of `String` class. The answer does say the right thing at the right place, although it could be less terse.

Comment: So you argue that pointing at the documentation is a suitable answer for any "How can I do XY in XYZ" question? Additionally, to me this answer looks like a tricky way to not become flagged as low quality automatically.

Comment: I argue that there are different situations that require different answers. The question in question no longer serves the original asker, it's on SO for other Ruby newbies who google it up. And they learn about `#upcase` and `#downcase` from the accepted answer plus a lot of related things from the rest of the numerous answers, including the one you don't like, each of which is trying to contribute its 2 cents of relevant information and thus scrape some reputation for the authors from SO visitors.

Comment: Questions on SO generally shouldn’t just serve the OP. I’m not sure I get how this question and the answers are any different from other questions and answers. Just because of the likelihood somebody will find it via Google?

Comment: Look, the question itself is a very basic question. Not really a programming problem, it rather belongs to SO Documentation. But that's OK. And so are the answers. You have to be nice to them. They are newbies helping newbies and trying to get some reputation by finding their space on the sun in these simple questions. That's why this question has 16 answers, all of them simple. The question itself is also basically unneeded, but it helps SO to be on top in Google. It's just a computer game after all :-)

Answer (score 3):

Out of 350K views, 100 people have bothered to upvote the answer that says *"you can use this method to print all methods available on a class"*.

That means that a hundred people out of those three hundred and fifty thousand found that answer "good", for whatever criteria they used to determine "goodness".

You really can't, and shouldn't try to, understand why other people find something good. For all that matter, all they thought was *"Hey, now I can see what methods are available without going to the online documentation!"*.

Comment: Okay. I see that some people might find this really helpful. But I still believe this doesn’t belong there – as an answer, as comment it would be perfectly fine. It just hides some other useful answers and attracts follow ups like http://stackoverflow.com/a/16803336/1779477.

Comment: @idmean so downvote it, and let it go. I don't consider a hundred votes on an answer posted in 2009 as a lot myself -  votes tend to [keep on trickling in](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305572/is-there-some-backstory-to-this-highly-upvoted-wrong-answer). Given enough time, the number of votes on content becomes meaningless in my opinion. Plenty of those votes are probably cast without even looking at the question, a web search simply pointed someone to the answer directly.

Comment: my criteria used to determine "goodness" for this answer was that 3 other people upvoted this, i should do the same lol

Comment: just my personal reminder: while you can find if the answer is good according to the score, if you determine to vote the answer,you should vote for the context of answer instead of the score,for example, you should not upvote the answer just because the answer has already many upvotes